# Execute script in specific frame

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can only see how to execute a script in the top level frame or in all frames in a certain tab:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(integer tabId, object details, function callback)
```

Where if `details.allFrames` is `true` then it will be executed in each subframe, but if it is false, it will only execute in the top level frame.  How can I provide a `frameId` to execute the script in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. Instead, set `allFrames: true` and write javascript in the content script to detect if it is the correct frame, and return without doing anything if it is not the correct frame.

Comment: I guess that will have to do...  Sigh.  Any tips on detecting what frame the thing is executing in?

Comment: You can get the document URL in the content script and check if it is the script you want

Comment: This just all seems wrong - why can't you specify a `frameId`?  Fine, I'll stop whining.

Comment: See below. You can add frameId.

Answer (score 2):

This is the route I went to solve this same problem:

https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/blob/master/chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame/chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame.js

```
function alertCookie(tabId, frameId) {
chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame(tabId, {
    frameId: frameId,
    code: '// This code runs in one frame, specified via frameId \n' +
          'alert(location.href);' +
          'document.cookie;'
}, function(results) {
    if (!results) {
        alert('Failed to execute code. See background page for details.');
        return;
    }
    var cookie = results[0];
    alert('Found cookie: ' + cookie);
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

If allFrames is true, implies that the JavaScript or CSS should be injected into all frames of current page. By default, it's false and is only injected into the top frame. If true and frameId is set, then the code is inserted in the selected frame and all of its child frames.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Chrome 39](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) there is an optional parameter named `frameId`.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(e) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(e.tabId, {
        frameId: e.frameId,      // <== LOOK HERE
        code: "console.log('hello');"
    });
});
```